# Exporting a NavBar with props for selected page

Tags: reactjs, import, navigation, export

I am exporting the navbar to navigation.js but I also want to export the selected pageLink
so that navigation.js knows which page to render.  But, whatever I try, I cannot.  This seems like a trivial thing but reactJS imposes the strangest restrictions...

... you would think, if this was any other environment, that, having imported a component, you would have access to anything within that component, but not in reactJS!

How can I pass this parameter, along with the navbar itself, to the navigation component?

navbar code:

```
case "Tile7":
       console.log("SetAllTileStyles [" + eventTileName + "] for [" + eventAction + "]");
      divToChange = document.getElementById('Tile5');
      divToChange.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
      divToChange.style.fontFamily = 'londrinaBookRegular';
      divToChange.style.color = 'yellow';

       // set remaining tiles to default
       SetDivToDefault("Tile1", eventAction);
       SetDivToDefault("Tile2", eventAction);
       SetDivToDefault("Tile3", eventAction);
       SetDivToDefault("Tile4", eventAction); 
       SetDivToDefault("Tile5", eventAction); 
       SetDivToDefault("Tile6", eventAction); 
       
       // Navigate to the appropriate page
       setPageLink("Engage");
 break; // end of Case Tile7 

return (
        ... divs for Tiles 1-6...

        <div
          id="Tile7"
          className="linkcontainer"
          onClick={HandleClick}
          onMouseEnter={e => HandleMouseEnter(e)}
          onMouseLeave={e => HandleMouseLeave(e)}
         >Engage
        </div> 
     ) // end Return

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example. Please also include where and how it's used, clearer details about what isn't working as expected, and what the actual and expected results should be.

Answer (score 0):

Would be really helpful if you could provide a CodeSandbox link.
Although I am guessing you're trying to pass data back to the parent from the child component.

The setPageLink function, instead of defining in the Navbar component which I am assuming is the child component, you can define it in the parent and pass it as props to this Navbar component.

so, to summarise

```
function Parent(props) {
  const [link, setPageLink] = useState('Engage');
  return <Child setPageLink={setPageLink}/>;
}

function Child({setPageLink}) {
   // use setPageLink from props like this setPageLink("Hi");
   // ... your child component
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to use the props method but ran into State illegality issues when importing the state constant into Navigation.js.

I almost got around it this way:

```
export default Navbar
export const pageToDisplay  = pageLink; 
// where pageLink is just a simple constant (no State)

import { Navbar, pageToDisplay } from "./Navbar.js";
```

so it is working better now, inasmuch as I get the default page which is "Home".

However, when I click on the Navbar it runs the HandleClick code but does not force a re-export of the updated pageLink, though it must be exporting something because the colour changes in the navbar !!

I am not sure how to fix that!  I am pretty sure I can't add an export statement in a child function...

I also get conflicting error messages if I use an upper case letter for the page name - as in "Home" and if I use a lower case letter at the start as in "home"...

The "components" I refer to are not functions - they are separate files in src/components.  Can I still pass Props to these files?  I guess I am already doing that in effect with the export and import statements...

Thank you so much for taking the trouble to reply.  I really appreciate it :-)

Comment: `import Navbar, { pageLink } from "./Navbar.js";` works as well and is more succinct and DRY. Did you intend to answer your own question (and raise more) or did you mean to update your current question?

Comment: I thought I had solved the problem but, as you say, I ended up updating the current question.  The issue here is that the on-click event is drive by the div code:
                <div
              id="Tile7"
              className="linkcontainer"
              onClick={HandleClick}
              onMouseEnter={e => HandleMouseEnter(e)}
              onMouseLeave={e => HandleMouseLeave(e)}
             >Engage
            </div>        
            </>           
        </div>

which is generated by the Navbar Component Module and includes the HandleClick function.

Comment: This function changes the colour and font of the clicked tile but, because it is a child function, it cannot force an export with the selected tile to the Navigation module unless I can figure out how to generate a conditional export somehow...

Answer (score 0):

Filling the React Hole...

I now have a working Navbar in my single page website, which does not require react-router, and the NavBar does not have to be in the index.js file where the router code would normally sit.

Instead of router, this app uses the export function to export the name of the page selected by the user.

Normally, when a user clicks a navbar tile, the HandleClick function does not produce an export, and nothing happens.

To get around this, I save the required page in a cookie (npm sfCookies) and then run the javascript pageRefresh function which forces an export.

In the export statement I read the required page from the cookie.

```
export default Navbar;
export const pageToInclude = read_cookie('savedpage');
```

The Navbar exports to the Header which assembles all the Header components, including the Navbar, and exports to a pageAssembly module which attaches the required page and the subsidiary page sections.

You could also achieve this by saving the page name in a database.

You need to save it somewhere permanent because refreshPage reloads the page from cache and that will wipe out any variables you have set.

You cannot use a state constant either because when you update the pageName it won't take effect until the next render and when refreshPage runs that render will not have taken place.

This way, its only a few lines of code, and you can have your navbar wherever you want it and you don't need react-router at all.

:-)